# Why can't I declare a FILE * with Stdio.h included

Tags: c, file, embedded

I have an `unknown type name 'FILE'` even though `stdio.h` is included.

I'm working on a Renesas RX210 with E2Studio compiling with GNURX ELF v14.03.

If the reason is that I can't use FILE on my RX210, can you tell me another way to do this?

Because I'm creating an [Opus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format)) [codec](https://opus-codec.org/) on the RX210, so I have to encode/decode files...

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "opus.h"
#include <stdio.h>

/*The frame size is hardcoded for this sample code but it doesn't have to be*/
#define FRAME_SIZE 960
#define SAMPLE_RATE 48000
#define CHANNELS 2
#define APPLICATION OPUS_APPLICATION_AUDIO
#define BITRATE 64000

#define MAX_FRAME_SIZE 6*960
#define MAX_PACKET_SIZE (3*1276)

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   char *inFile;
   FILE *fin;
   char *outFile;
   FILE *fout;
   /* Lot of things here */
}
```

---

The error message is:

> unknown type name 'FILE' Opus_main.c /Opus/src line 20 C/C++ Problem

Comment: Can you show exactly what error message you received when you compiled this code?

Comment: What makes you say that you can't declare it as such?

Comment: "unknown type name 'FILE' Opus_main.c /Opus/src line 20 C/C++ Problem"

I think the problem comes from my compiler "GNURX", because i'm working on a Renesas RX210...

So, i though that my Renesas cannot use FILE, but i still need to use it, so i'm looking for a solution

Comment: What is line 20, please? This one: `FILE *fout;`?

Comment: But `<stdio.h>` successfully gets included? Please show the complete compiler output. If removing `#include "opus.h"` still gives this error, remove it here; otherwise, show us opus.h

Comment: And what is in `opus.h`? Try moving the `#include` for `opus.h` after the `#include` for `stdio.h`.

Comment: Looks like the Renesas RX210 is an embedded processor which does not support any storage (out of the box). So you can't use file i/o, because you don't have a filesystem. If you use an external filesystem library, you have to use it's API.

Comment: If you cannot legally use `FILE` you do not have a C compiler for *hosted implementation*. C compilers for *freestanding implementations* are not required to provide features from `<stdio.h>`

Comment: Line 20 is the FILE * fin;

But after looking at Wimmel's answer, it looks like that the Renesas doesn't have a filesystem, so i can't declare a FILE *.

So i'm looking for a solution of filesystem driver on the Renesas webstite,

Thx you for you answers all, if you know how to use FileSystem on Renesas RX210, you can answer again :)

Comment: What kind of device are you attempting to communicate with if you don't have a file system?  In most cases even where stream I/O is supported in the library, you would need to provide your own low-level I/O retargetting code to map it to the actual I/O device, unless it is an off-the-shelf board with vendor supplied stubs?